# In what scenarios should IF statements be used over CASE in SQL

Tags: sql, select, stored-procedures, if-statement, case

I am writing a stored procedure to query a DB.

Parameters are passed to the procedure for the where clause.

I just can't seem to find anywhere a description of the pros and cons of SQL IF and CASE statements. Can anyone give me a reason why i should use one of these staements over the other or if im going in the wrong direction completely?

method 1:

```
DECLARE @SQL_WHERE_QUERY NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
IF @SQL_PARAM IS NOT NULL SET @SQL_WHERE_QUERY = @SQL_WHERE_QUERY + ' AND [COLUMN_NAME] = '''+@SQL_PARAM+''''
```

method 2:

```
DECLARE @SQL_WHERE_QUERY NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
SET @SQL_WHERE_QUERY = CASE WHEN @SQL_PARAM IS NOT NULL THEN ' AND [COLUMN_NAME] = '''+@SQL_PARAM+'''' END
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your two code snippets are not the same.

The `if` version does not change the value of `@SQL_WHERE_QUERY`, because there is no `else` statement with a `set`.  The `case` version sets the variable to `NULL`.

In the specific case of using `if`/`else` to set a variable value, the `if` and the `case` should be equivalent.

Otherwise, the two are quite different.  `if` executes a block of code, so you can have `begin`/`end` statements, with arbitrarily complex T-SQL code.  The `case` is used just for the expression and only allows constructs allowed in a `select` statement.

Personally, I would generally use `if` with `set`, and `case` in SQL statements.

Comment: The reason i have no ELSE in the IF statement is because i don't need the column to be included in the query if the parameter is null.

So generally an IF statement is used for more complex situations is it?

Comment: @Hiky . . . The two are quite different.  `if` is a control flow statement in T-SQL (which allows for "more complex" statements).  The `case` statement is used for expressions within a query.  It so happens that such expressions can be used with `set`, which is why you are confusing them.